# Table Column structure decimal

Tags: jquery, mysql, database

I want to store rating values into my table as is.

Ratings are from 0.0 to 5.0 (using rateYo jQuery plugin)

My rating column is decimal(3.2)

But whenever I try to insert a rating value with decimal points it will get rounded down. 3.5 = 4.

Or should I just leave it as is?

Will I still be able to get an accurate average rating if all individual ratings are rounded down when inserted into the table?

3.4 + 3.6 / 2 = 3.5 = 4
3 + 4 / 2 = 3.5 = 4

so its still the same but that's only for 2 ratings. What if there were hundreds of them with random values (3.22, 3.5, etc.)

Comment: What is the data type of the column in your table that you are inserting this value into? How does `3.5 = 4` mean `rounded down`?

Comment: Its decimal(3.2)

rounded down like the round math formula.

3.4 = 3, 3.5 = 4, 1.2 = 1, 1.4 = 1, 1.8 = 2

Comment: Ok, I mean I just interpret 'down' as like... down.. when 3.5 is rounded to 4, I perceive that as 'up'. Anyway, it doesn't matter. Cheers

Comment: If you select 3.4 + 3.6 / 2 what do you get (I get 5.2)?

Comment: @P.Salmon

You followed MDAS rule for equations. You misunderstood, i'm trying to get the average rating so it's a different equations.

It's not 3.4 + 3.6 / 2 but (3.4+3.6) / 2

Answer (score 0):

Your field is defined as decimal(3.2) mysql does not throw an error on this 'invalid' (quoted because this may be what you intended) definition (it probably should be 3,2) but seems to treat it like an integer.

*If a number is inserted into an exact type column (DECIMAL or integer), it is inserted with its exact value if it is within the column range.
If the value has too many digits in the fractional part, rounding occurs and a warning is generated. Rounding is done as described in Section 12.21.4, “Rounding Behavior”* - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-expressions.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-rounding.html